# Sticky navigation only if bigger than 960px

Tags: jquery, navigation, sticky

I have a question about jquery. I'm trying to apply a sticky navigation only if the window size is bigger than 960px. So I need to check if there is a window resizing or a scrolling event... I can't figure it out...

May someone please help me fixing that stuff?

Here's the code I tried to adapt

```
$(function() {

    var sticky_navigation_offset_top = $('#nav').offset().top;

    var sticky_navigation = function(){
        var scroll_top = $(window).scrollTop(); // our current vertical position from the top

        if (scroll_top > sticky_navigation_offset_top) { 
            $('#nav').css({ 'position': 'fixed', 'top':0, 'left':0 });


        } else {
            $('#nav').css({ 'position': 'relative' }); 
        }   
    };

    sticky_navigation();

    $(window).resize(function() {
  if ($(window).width() > 960) {
        $(window).scroll(function() {
         sticky_navigation();
    });
  }
});
});
```

Comment: Having a handler within a handler seems odd to me. You can string them  together, if you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

roXon is not taking the nav offset into consideration and the calculation has to be made on resize and on scroll too.

Here's my solution: http://jsfiddle.net/victmo/SZV6m/

Im  using jquery's 1.8 `on` function: `win.on('resize scroll', function(){...`

**Javascript**

```
var minWidthToStick = 300;

var nav = $('#nav'); // caching nav
var offset = nav.offset().top; // getting offset
var win = $(window); // caching window

win.on('resize scroll', function(){
    if(
        win.width() >= minWidthToStick && 
        win.scrollTop() >= offset
    ){
        nav.css('position', 'fixed');
    }else{
        nav.css('position', 'relative');
    }
}).resize();
```

Don't forget to put that code inside your `$(document).ready(function(){ ... })` function :)

Comment: Glad to hear that Jhon, Cheers!

Comment: Yup, did it like this

$(document).ready(function(){
 
var minWidthToStick = 960;

var nav = $('#nav'); // caching nav
var offset = nav.offset().top; // getting offset
var win = $(window); // caching window

 win.on('resize scroll', function(){
     console.log(win.scrollTop());
     if(
         win.width() >= minWidthToStick && 
         win.scrollTop() >= offset
     ){
         nav.css('position', 'fixed');
     }else{
         nav.css('position', 'relative');
     }
 }).resize();
});

Works perfect !

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/iwasew/2/edit)**</kbd>

```
function stickNav() { 
    var setPosition = $(window).width() > 960 ? 'fixed' : 'relative';
    $('#nav').css({position:setPosition, left:0, top:0});
}


$(function() {
    stickNav();  // Do it on DOM ready
});

$(window).resize(function() {
    stickNav();  // Do in on Resize
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Comment: roXon many thanks! Works perfect ! One thing, at start my nav is not sticky, needs to be in relative position ! That's why I used the scroll function when I reached the menu, the relative position changed to Fixed !

What do I need to add to use it?

See the results here http://projects.faver.be/faver2013/#

Thanks again !

Comment: @jhon neither mine is sticky. I don't know what you mean. Can you setup a demo?

Comment: My example? It doesn't work on resize!

Try to resize the window, the menu is still sticky. What I need is to have a sticky menu ONLY if the window size is bigger than 960px and if we reach the menu using the scroll.

Do u know what i mean ? :)